# PHP execute command on remote Windows computer with administrator rights

Tags: php, windows, lamp

I am currently creating a computer management intranet site using a LAMP web server and PHP running on an Ubuntu server. To remotely shutdown domain connected machines, I usually run a shutdown command in command prompt on my machine, that tells the PCs to shutdown via Active Directory.

Is there a way to connect to a remote Windows machine from Apache on Ubuntu and run the command under an account with domain admin privileges? If possible, I would not like to have a password in plain text in the PHP script, so can this be achieved using public keys or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Will let you run command line programs that will help you automate this process, it could let you execute a batch file to do what you're looking for